# Cannot access public properties of my base user control from my derived user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, user-controls, webusercontrol

I have created a User control as follows:

```
public class Controls_Custom_Base : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<string> MyList;
}
```

I have then derived another control from this it as follows:

```
public class Controls_Custom_Derived : Controls_Custom_Base
{

}
```

I would like to access MyList from this derived class but I cannot see it. I have tried using:

```
base.MyList
```

and have also tried changing the MyList to a property with get/set methods but this does not work either!

Comment: Where are you trying to do it? What happens when you try? A short but complete example of trying to access it along with the error message would really help. Additionally, I'd strongly encourage you to embrace .NET naming conventions - ditch the underscores...

Comment: Everything should be OK, check it again. Also, *protected* would be better than *public*.

Comment: I am able to access without any issue:
 public class Controls_Custom_Base : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public List<string> MyList;
    }
  public class Controls_Custom_Derived : Controls_Custom_Base
    {
        public void GetParentData()
        {
            var list = base.MyList;
        }
    }

Comment: Ok I've sorted it.  It was some issue with the dll's being cached.  I deleted the files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files, rebuilt and now it works, although the intelisense is still not working.  At least the code runs now!  Thanks